# R- Merge csv file with shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

I would like to merge shapefile with a data frame and I receive the following error

Error in match(bx, by, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments

My code is

```
mydat <- read.csv("PLS.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)

mydat<- mydat %>% rename_at(vars(STABR),~"STATE") 
mydat<- mydat %>% rename_at(vars(CNTY),~"COUNTY") 

mydat <- mydat[ ! mydat$STATE %in% c("AS","GU"), ]

states <- readOGR("cb_2015_us_state_20m.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2015_us_state_20m")#,stringsAsFactors = F)


states <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% setdiff(states$STUSPS,c("AS","GU","PR")))

states$STUSPS <- states[order(states$STUSPS), ]

map_dat <- mydat[,c("STATE",
                    "LIBNAME",  
                    "ADDRESS",
                    "CITY",
                    "ZIP",
                    "COUNTY",
                    "GEOCODE",
                    "LONGITUD",
                    "LATITUDE")]


projects.df <- merge(states, map_dat, by.x = "STUSPS", by.y = "STATE",duplicateGeoms = T)
```

Can anyone help me to detect where I went wrong?

Comment: Do you want your end result to be a data frame or a shapefile?

Comment: @CAWA: I would like a shapefile

Comment: You might try adding a new column to the data portion of your existing shapefile.
states@data$new info.
Also this might help even though it is closed https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64174/how-to-add-a-field-to-a-shapefile-using-r

Comment: @CAWA: If I add new column to the data portion, will the shapedfile still be used to make a map in leaflet?

Comment: @CAWA: How about I want the end result to be a data frame?

Comment: I advise you te read about (and use) the `sf` package for these kind of problems.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you add data to the shape file it should maintain its spatial reference and can be used in the map. If you want to take data from the shape file and add it to a data frame use the same code again states@data$xxxxx <-df$xxxxx. [this should help too](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115259/convert-shapefile-with-lists-to-data-frame-in-r)